# Replacing a row value with the most frequent value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, max

I have dataframe as below:

```
   |            types | freq   |     TypeList
0  |    Q11424 (item) |   29   |   Q11424 (item),Q571 (item)
1  |      Q571 (item) |   9    |   Q11424 (item),Q571 (item)
0  |    Q11012 (item) |   6    |   Q11012 (item)
0  |  Q4830453 (item) |   39   |   Q4830453 (item)
0  |  Q7725634 (item) |   2    |   Q7725634 (item),Q571 (item)
1  |      Q571 (item) |   9    |   Q7725634 (item),Q571 (item)
0  |   Q785479 (item) |   1    |   Q785479 (item),Q1344 (item)
1  |     Q1344 (item) |   1    |   Q785479 (item),Q1344 (item)
```

column 'types' is actually a flattened column of 'TypeList'.  And freq column indicates frequency of each value in column types. These frequencies are from whole dataframe. Here I am just adding few of those rows. E.g. Q571 occurred 9 times in types column and hence has freq=9. TypeList column is a list of types for each record. I want to add new column SuperType which will have most frequent type if the TypeList column will contain more than one type. E.g. I want following result:

```
   |            types | freq   |     TypeList                   |SuperType
0  |    Q11424 (item) |   29   |   Q11424 (item),Q571 (item)    | Q11424
1  |      Q571 (item) |   9    |   Q11424 (item),Q571 (item)    | Q11424
0  |    Q11012 (item) |   6    |   Q11012 (item)                | Q11012
0  |  Q4830453 (item) |   39   |   Q4830453 (item)              | Q4830453
0  |  Q7725634 (item) |   2    |   Q7725634 (item),Q571 (item)  | Q571
1  |      Q571 (item) |   9    |   Q7725634 (item),Q571 (item)  | Q571
0  |   Q785479 (item) |   1    |   Q785479 (item),Q1344 (item)  | Q785479
1  |     Q1344 (item) |   1    |   Q785479 (item),Q1344 (item)  | Q785479
```

In the first row, TypeList column has value "Q11424 (item),Q571 (item)". So I want to check frequencies of both these types i.e. 29 and 9 resp. and assign the most frequent type in superType column for that row, i.e. Q11424 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `transform`

```
df['SuperType']=df.sort_values('freq').groupby('TypeList')['types'].transform('last')
df['SuperType']=df.SuperType.str[:-6]
df.sort_index()
Out[1124]: 
             types  freq                     TypeList  SuperType
0    Q11424 (item)    29    Q11424 (item),Q571 (item)    Q11424 
1      Q571 (item)     9    Q11424 (item),Q571 (item)    Q11424 
2    Q11012 (item)     6                Q11012 (item)    Q11012 
3  Q4830453 (item)    39              Q4830453 (item)  Q4830453 
4  Q7725634 (item)     2  Q7725634 (item),Q571 (item)      Q571 
5      Q571 (item)     9  Q7725634 (item),Q571 (item)      Q571 
6   Q785479 (item)     1  Q785479 (item),Q1344 (item)     Q1344 
7     Q1344 (item)     1  Q785479 (item),Q1344 (item)     Q1344
```

Edit :

```
df=df.sort_values('freq')
df['SuperType']=df.groupby('TypeList')['types'].transform('last').values
df['SuperType']=df.SuperType.str[:-6]
```

Comment: I am getting "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" exception after executing first line. The exception occurrs only if I try to assign the value to df['superType'], otherwise it works.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot! :) But can you please explain what exactly have u done? what is tranform('last') and why it is str[:-6]?

Comment: for transform :https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.transform.html 

for str[:-6] slice the string from last 6 position to the beginning